# How to make Rhythmbox toggle between pause and play with spacebar?

Tags: rhythmbox, shortcuts

When ever i press <kbd>Space</kbd> in Rhythmbox the song starts over instead of going on pause and when its on pause and i press <kbd>Space</kbd> the song starts over again instead of resuming from where it left of.

So my question is how can i change this so it will toggle between pause/play?

Comment: Does this Q&A help - if so, we should perhaps close this as a dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/181651/how-to-assign-hot-keys-to-control-rhythmbox

Comment: no, i want to change the "CTRL" + "SPACE" in the program to only "SPACE", so i can press space to toggle between pause and play, and  it must only be while the program is open(not minimized just like how the "CTRL" + "SPACE" is now).

Answer (score 6):

rythymbox's keyboard interface is incoherent.

The desired behaviour, (which imo is desired behaviour for all music players at all times,) of space bar being play/pause button, is actually possible after you click play or pause with the mouse. It is like it 'selects' that button.

However, after you select a track for example, the spacebar behaviour changes to selecting that track, so everytime you press pause, I mean spacebar, it will again select that track, and because it is playing it will start playing the track again. I hope this will get fixed sometime into something more sensible and intuitive. Like the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You have to press "Ctrl+P" to play/pause apparently (at least on Gnome in Ubuntu 20.04, where I tested it).

For some reason this information is not easily accessible.

See https://help.gnome.org/users/rhythmbox/stable/shortcuts.html.en for more.

Comment: Any way to change this? I want to use only SPACE as my default key to play/pause.

Comment: I've looked for a way to do this, but haven't found one. Let me know if you do!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the source, as space in a tree typically means "activate the current selection." And this describes the behavior you're seeing exactly.

However, it does appear that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> gives your desired behavior.

Comment: thanks :D do you know how i can change it so when i press "CTRL" the same will happen as when pressing "CTRL"+"SPACE" ?

Comment: As Ctrl is a modifier key, you can't really make it do something when you press only that key. You will have to press it along with another key. If you want a single key for play/pause, I'd recommend a multimedia keyboard if you don't already have one. If you do have one, the play/pause key on it should do what you want. :)

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong, i meant "SPACE" not "CTRL"

Answer (score 1):

You are ~probably supposed to also be able to change the setting for global play-pause in gnome-control-center -> All Settings -> Keyboard -> Play (or Play/Pause), which I think is by default set to Control-Space.

But, it won't let you set Space as an option since that would conflict with other applications.  It's also not working for me at the moment; there might be other pieces of gnome that I don't have loaded cause I'm not running a full gnome desktop.

This isn't really a solution, but at least provides a bit more info on the misbehaving subsystems.

Comment: also, in the time it takes rhythmbox to load, cmus can index your entire library from scratch.  use space, tab, and arrow keys to navigate, then the c key is you play/pause button.  Don't try to play an aac file, or it will blast static at a deafening volume.

Comment: Why isn't this answer on the top?!