# Rhythmbox pause/resume with space key

Tags: 12.10, rhythmbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Rhythmbox toogle between pause and play with spacebar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176775/how-to-make-rhythmbox-toogle-between-pause-and-play-with-spacebar)

I am currently using Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 12.10, and I like it in all aspects, except for one -- space key's function. Currently space key starts the current song from the beginning, which I have seen only on Rhythmbox. Usually space key pauses or resumes the playback, and that's what I am used to and would like it to do.

I haven't found a setting for that, but I am pretty sure there must be a setting for it somewhere. So how could I make space bar pause/resume the playback?